How to get another window viewpoint while sculpting?
I would like to be able to hae a seperate "final camera angle" view ona seperate window while I sculpt a model in blender as my main screen.
Ive currently using Window>new Window.
But this resets everytime I open Blender

For whatever reason it blocks drop down menus behind it. Like if i want to switch from Sculpt to a diff mode the Window blocks that.


Also the camera view leaves all this extra space on the outside, and when I resize the new window it makes everything smaller proportionally to keep that empty space outside the camera.
Any work arounds for any of these issues would be appreciated.

Does this answer your question? split screens in 2.8

You need to create split window within tab as demonstrated in this video.
You can create multiple split windows and maximize those windows by Ctrl+Space each (or Ctrl+CTRL to go back). You can also create multiple cameras and then switch between them, but I found it to be a more tedious process.
This won't block anything and your setup will be saved in the .blend file.

Thanks for the posts. This is not a regular forum, according to site rules links to answers are not answers if the link goes missing your answer becomes an empty shell without content. Answers should be substantial and stand on their own without relying on external data like links, videos or images. Instead of having users go through external links, either transcribe essential parts of the process here, linking the source, or posts these in the comments section instead.

Thanks, btw is tehre any way for the perspective camera from the new split window to be saved to a camera while removing that annoying border? I want to have 2-3 views that I switch back and forth from and would like a way to sve and toogle them

You can create multiple split windows and maximalize those windows by CTRL + Space each (or CTRL + Space to go back).
You can also create multiple cameras and then switch between them (but i found it more tedious process).

For the multiple cameras, how do you remove the border?

Basically I just want multiple perspective views that i can control in isolation of each other, but want to also have them saved to a camera incase I move the view by accident and want to have a backup
